# Cannot get this specific class above 75% for testing help SOS

Tags: trigger, code-coverage

public class SurveyRulesNameTriggerHandler_AC {

```
public static void onBeforeInsert(List<Survey_Rules__c> newSurveyRules){
    
    //Find trigger names already taken besides SEOCSMEDAL
    List<Survey_Rules__c> triggerNames=new List<Survey_Rules__c>([SELECT Trigger_Name__c FROM Survey_Rules__c WHERE Trigger_Name__c != 'SEOCSMEDAL']);
    map<String,Survey_Rules__c> rulesmap=new map<String,Survey_Rules__c>();
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:triggerNames){
        rulesmap.put(rules.Trigger_Name__c,rules);
    }
    
    //Prevent users from saving when this is found
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:newSurveyRules){
        if((rulesmap.get(rules.Trigger_Name__c)!=null)){
            rules.adderror('Trigger Name already exists.');
        }
    }
    
}

public static void onBeforeInsert2(List<Survey_Rules__c> newSurveyRules){
    
    //Find trigger names already taken besides SEOCSMEDAL
    List<Survey_Rules__c> surveyNames=new List<Survey_Rules__c>([SELECT Survey_Name__c FROM Survey_Rules__c WHERE Active__c = true]);
    map<String,Survey_Rules__c> rulesmap=new map<String,Survey_Rules__c>();
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:surveyNames){
        rulesmap.put(rules.Survey_Name__c,rules);
    }
    
    //Prevent users from saving when this is found
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:newSurveyRules){
        if((rulesmap.get(rules.Survey_Name__c)!=null)){
            rules.adderror('Active Survey Rule already created for that Survey Name.');
        }
    }
    
}

public static void onBeforeUpdate(List<Survey_Rules__c> newSurveyRules, map<Id,Survey_Rules__c> oldmap){
    
    //Find trigger names already taken besides SEOCSMEDAL
    List<Survey_Rules__c> triggerNames=new List<Survey_Rules__c>([SELECT Trigger_Name__c FROM Survey_Rules__c WHERE Trigger_Name__c != 'SEOCSMEDAL']);
    map<String,Survey_Rules__c> rulesmap=new map<String,Survey_Rules__c>();
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:triggerNames){
        rulesmap.put(rules.Trigger_Name__c,rules);
    }
    
    //Prevent users from saving when this is found
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:newSurveyRules){
        if((oldmap.get(rules.id).Trigger_Name__c!=rules.Trigger_Name__c)&&(rulesmap.get(rules.Trigger_Name__c)!=null)){
            rules.adderror('Trigger Name already exists.');
        }
    }
    
}

public static void onBeforeUpdate2(List<Survey_Rules__c> newSurveyRules, map<Id,Survey_Rules__c> oldmap){
    
    //Find trigger names already taken besides SEOCSMEDAL
    List<Survey_Rules__c> surveyNames=new List<Survey_Rules__c>([SELECT Survey_Name__c FROM Survey_Rules__c WHERE Active__c = true]);
    map<String,Survey_Rules__c> rulesmap=new map<String,Survey_Rules__c>();
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:surveyNames){
        rulesmap.put(rules.Survey_Name__c,rules);
    }
    
    //Prevent users from saving when this is found
    for(Survey_Rules__c rules:newSurveyRules){
        if((oldmap.get(rules.id).Survey_Name__c!=rules.Survey_Name__c)&&(rulesmap.get(rules.Survey_Name__c)!=null)){
            rules.adderror('Active Survey Rule already created for that Survey Name.');
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: Please do not repost questions that have been closed. Resources for working on code coverage were linked on your [previous question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313179/help-i-cannot-get-my-test-code-coverage-higher-than-75-code-below). The short answer is that you need to write unit tests that cover each individual code path.

Comment: I have been but it wont cover the error message no matter what technique I use